# Factorization of Polynomial without Polynomial Division

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How do I factorize $2p^3 -7p^2+8p+6$ without polynomial division? I know, that the solution is $(2p + 1)(p^2 - 4p + 6)$.

Comment: Take the constant term. Find its divisors, positive and negative. See if any of them satisfies the equation f(x) = 0. Then x-(factor) is one of the factors. Leave a line and on the next line start writing x-(factor) multiplied with the required terms. The line you left will start filling automatically and from there you can adjust how much do you need more or less of this factor. It works for any factorizable polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
$$2p^3 -7p^2+8p+6=2p^3+p^2-8p^2-4p+12p+6$$

Comment: Lovely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A real cubic polynomial has at least one real root. Fetch!

Classically, try some easy values first. So what if $p=0$? $P(0) = 6$. And  $p=1$? $P(1) = 9$. Unlucky. So $p=-1$? $P(-1) = -11$. So there is (a least) a root between $-1$ and $0$.

Keep it simple. Try dichotomy. $P(-1/2) = 0$? **Bingo**! From now try to find $(p+1/2)$ terms. You are quite safe now. You can collect $2$-ratios (8 and 4, 6 and 3) between some $x^p$ and $x^{p-1}$ coefficients.

First, $8p+6=(2\times 4)p+(4) +2 = 8(p+1/2)+2$. 
Then $2p^3−7p^2=(2\times 1)p^3+(1)p^2−8p^2 = (p+1/2)(2p^2)−8p^2$.

So you already have: 
$$2p^3−7p^2+8p+6 = (p+1/2)(2p^2)−8p^2+ 8(p+1/2)+2 = (p+1/2)(2p^2+8)-8p^2+2 \,. $$

As you know that $-1/2$ is a root, you recognize that $-8p^2+2=-8(p+1/2)(p-1/2)$. Hence you have:
$$(p+1/2)(2p^2+8)-8p^2+2 = (p+1/2)(2p^2+8-8(p-1/2)) = (p+1/2)(2p^2-8p+12)\,.$$

You are almost done (by a factor of $2$).